# Using CakePHP 3.5's $this->response->withFile() Function to Return a JPG File

Tags: php, cakephp, httpresponse, cakephp-3.x, cakephp-3.5

I'm trying to read a file and return it with a controller in CakePHP 3.5 and I'm not having much luck.

I have a quick test file sitting in the /webroot directory with 777 permissions and am trying to return it with this code:

```
public function thumbnail( $order_id = null, $image_id = null ) {

    $this->response->withFile( $order_id.'-'.$image_id.'.jpg' );
    return $this->response;
}
```

When I hit that controller (ie. /orders/thumbnail/KC9BW0/1) All I get back in the browser is a zero byte page with 'text/html' type.

I can't find anything on StackOverflow or the web in general giving a simple example of this using the withFile() function in as recommended in the 3.5 documentation. What am I missing?

Comment: From my reading of the documentation, it seems you may have to provide it with a full path, not just a file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the docs again, your code is slightly different:

> ```
> public function sendFile($id)
> {
>     $file = $this->Attachments->getFile($id);
>     $response = $this->response->withFile($file['path']);
>     // Return the response to prevent controller from trying to render
>     // a view.
>     return $response;
> }
> ```
>
> As shown in the above example, you must pass the file path to the method. [...]

Response objects are immutable, you did not reassign the object, thus you are returning an unmodified response object, and as already stated in the comments, you should pass a path, an **absolute path**, not just a filename, otherwise the file will be looked up in whatever the `APP` constant points to!

See also

- **[Cookbook > Controllers > Request & Response Objects > Response > Sending Files](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#sending-files)**
- **[Cookbook > Controllers > Request & Response Objects > Common Mistakes with Immutable Responses](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#common-mistakes-with-immutable-responses)**
- **[API > \Cake\Http\Response::withFile()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.5/class-Cake.Http.Response.html#_withFile)**